# Error in registerShinyDebugHook: attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating an R Shiny application using the following code. It is only 1 line.

UI.R

```
htmlTemplate("template.html", document_ = "FALSE",button = actionButton("action", "Action"))
```

With template.html being:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- Title and meta description -->
  <title>BLAH</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta property="og:description" content="" />
<!-- CSS  -->
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    background-color: white;
  }
  div.test {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "test">
        {{button}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I set document_ = "FALSE" in the htmlTemplate function, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in registerShinyDebugHook: attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

If I remove this option, I lose the CSS I need to make selectInput look pretty, but I no longer have an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. I see an action button, no matter if I set document_ TRUE or FALSE.